# Delete key takes to start of line on gnome 45

Tags: gnome, keyboard

My <kbd>Delete</kbd> key is misbehaving on Gnome. It was working fine on KDE and Windows.

I tried to turn on screencast mode on VSCode, but it says that I have pressed <kbd>Delete</kbd><kbd>Home</kbd> even though I had only pressed the <kbd>Delete</kbd> key. The Keyboard layout is correct (US English, I am using the same on KDE and Windows)

- keyboard layout: US English
- desktop environment: Gnome 45

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?